# Can't force flot number of ticks

Tags: javascript, flot

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/3519/) representing the problem.

I've seen many solutions here and on Google but they don't seem to work.
I've tried setting **tickSize** to 1, setting ticks as an **array** or **number** (15 in this case) and still the flot lib does as it pleases.

I've read the API doc so many times, I don't think I'm missing anything.

> If you want to completely override the tick algorithm, you can specify an array for "ticks", ...

Relevant snippet of code:

```
xaxis: {
    show: true,
    ticks: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
}
```

Does anyone have a solution? Feel free to edit the JSFiddle or just comment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had better luck defining `xaxis` outside of `series`.

The structure is not entirely clear in the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#user-content-customizing-the-axes).

```js
var options = {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true,
            fill: true,
            align: 'center'
        },
        shadowSize: 0

    },
    xaxis: {
        show: true,
        ticks: [[1,'test label'],2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
    }
};
```

```js
$(function() {

  var options = {
    series: {
      bars: {
        show: true,
        fill: true,
        align: 'center'
      },
      shadowSize: 0

    },
    xaxis: {
      show: true,
      ticks: [[1,'test label'], 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
    }
  };

  var d2 = [
    [1, 25],
    [2, 35],
    [3, 15],
    [4, 13],
    [5, 3],
    [6, 8],
    [7, 5],
    [8, 13],
    [9, 3],
    [10, 8],
    [11, 12],
    [12, 15],
    [13, 7],
    [14, 4],
    [15, 1]
  ];

  $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d2], options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<h1>Flot Examples</h1> 
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
```

Comment: You're right, the example could be more than a single line of code. Reading back through the documentation now I see that I have to remember the structure from many paragraphs behind. That finally worked, thank you!